# Tomcat Server is failed to run the Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat9

I am trying to run java applications by using tomcat server version 9 . When I created first project and project was running successfully but the problem is when I created another project and assign this project with the server , I am getting following errors .

**Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start.**

Here is code for index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<body>
<form action="login">
User Name:<input type="text" name="userName"/>
Password:<input type="password" name="userPassword"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Servlet code .

```
package Edureka;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
@WebServlet("/login")
public class MyServlet1 extends HttpServlet{
/**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) {
try{
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter pwriter = response.getWriter();
String name = request.getParameter("userName");
String password = request.getParameter("userPassword");
pwriter.print("Hello here:"+name);
pwriter.print(" Your Password is: "+password);
//Creating two cookies
Cookie c1=new Cookie("userName",name);
Cookie c2=new Cookie("userPassword",password);
//Adding the cookies to response header
response.addCookie(c1);
response.addCookie(c2);
pwriter.print("<a href='welcomehere'>View Details</a>");
pwriter.close();
}catch(Exception exp){
System.out.println(exp);
}
}
}
```

Here is the web.xml file .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>Cookies</display-name>
 <servlet>
<servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Edureka.MyServlet1</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Servlet2</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Edureka.MyServlet2</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Servlet2</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Here is screen shot when I tried to run it  in Eclipse..

[image]

Comment: What is the output in the Console View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `WebServlet` annotation and the `url-pattern` mapping in the deployment descriptor with the same URI. Only do that in one place.